# Help me find an old anime film

Tags: 3x3-eyes

Can you help me find the name of an anime film? I do not remember very much about it but here is what I recall:

1. It's a movie not a TV-show.
2. It's probably in the genre of horror because it includes monsters, blood and maybe some people dying.
3. It was made before 2005.
4. There is a boy who lives in a cave in the mountains with an old lady and he decides to go to the city (I don't know why).
5. A girl is run over by a bus and her blood is everywhere, but somehow she is not dead (like it was only a vision or time went backwards).
6. The girl has an older brother and I think they are orphans.
7. There is a young girl with three eyes.
8. There is a very large monster that resembles Ryuk from Death Note and maybe a bird monster.

Answer (score 6):

- **The anime you're looking for is [3x3 eyes](http://myanimelist.net/anime/300/3x3_Eyes)**

  [image]

  > **3X3 Eyes is the story of a young man named Yakumo Fuuji, who through a strange series of events becomes the immortal slave of the last of a race of 3 Eyed immortals. The immortal absorbs his soul to save his life, making him immortal in the process. Now, he begins a journey with the female immortal in an attempt to find a way of becoming human. Of course, there are many complications along the way, not the least of which being that the immortal is a female with a split personality, one achingly cute and the other being no-nonsense destructive power, and the romances that develop between.**
- The anime satisfies all of the points you mentioned except for

  > It is a movie not a TV-show

  I think you may have mistaken it for a movie. It's an OVA collection of 4 episodes having a [sequel](http://myanimelist.net/anime/1225/3x3_Eyes_Seima_Densetsu) of 3 another OVA episodes.
- The boy is [Yakumo Fujii](http://myanimelist.net/character/7160/Yakumo_Fujii), the three eyed girl is [Pai Sanjiyan](http://myanimelist.net/character/5492/Pai) and the large monster is [Benares](http://myanimelist.net/character/14075/Benares)